# Minha aplicação não salva dados acentuados corretamente

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, extjs-4

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web com ExtJS 4 e PHP. Estou com problemas na hora de fazer o `INSERT` no banco de dados. Por exemplo, cadastrei o produto "chá", porém ele salva "chu00e1". Todo o meu banco de dados está em UTF-8, meus arquivos PHP estão com *header* em UTF-8, meu HTML também, estou salvando meus arquivos em UTF-8, ou seja, tudo está com a mesma codificação.

Abaixo está a linha de código onde faço o `INSERT`.

```
<?php
//chama o arquivo de conexão com o bd
include("connect.php");

$info = $_POST['data'];

$data = json_decode(stripslashes($info));

$codigo = $data->codigo;
$nome = $data->nome;
$descricao = $data->descricao;
$quantidade = $data->quantidade;
$sigla = $data->sigla;


$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO produtos (codigo, nome, descricao, quantidade, sigla) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%s')",
    mysql_real_escape_string($codigo),
    mysql_real_escape_string($nome),
    mysql_real_escape_string($descricao),
    mysql_real_escape_string($quantidade),
    mysql_real_escape_string($sigla));

$rs = mysql_query($query);

echo json_encode(array(
    "success" => mysql_errno() == 0,
    "data" => array(
        "id" => mysql_insert_id(),
        "codigo" => $codigo,
        "nome" => $nome,
        "descricao" => $descricao,
        "quantidade" => $quantidade,
        "sigla" => $sigla
    )
));
?>
```

Comment: Dá uma lida na documentação:
[utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php)

Comment: Eu já tinha dado uma olhada lá. Não dá pra eu usar utf8_encode porque ela pede String como parâmetro e meus dados estão num array.

Comment: Isso não interfere em nada, voce está guardando uma string dentro do array :)
Tente: `$seuCampo= utf8_encode($data->seuCampo)`;

Comment: Na verdade tem que ser assim: 
`$string = $data->seuCampo;
$suaStringCodificada = utf8_encode($string);`

Comment: Não deu certo, cara..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É provável que o transporte dos dados do MySQL da biblioteca do PHP ao driver esteja com outra codificação. Quer dizer, a página está com a codificação certa, o banco de dados está gravando as coisas em UTF-8, mas o que chega à ele pode não ser UTF-8.
Para se certificar disso, no seu `connect.php`, rode a seguinte query:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conexao);
```

Isso vai evitar que você precise ficar convertendo (usar `utf8_encode()` ou `utf8_decode()`) na hora de gravar ou de exibir. Deve funcionar caso tudo esteja em UTF-8 como você diz.

### EDIT:

Na verdade o problema era a função `stripslashes` que removia a barra da codificação Unicode (Formato: \u0000) colocada pelo JSON no POST, fazendo a codificação ficar descaracterizada.
Vou deixar a resposta original pois pode ajudar em casos de problemas na acentuação, mas sei que não é a resposta certa no caso da pergunta.

Comment: Tentei isso, mas não deu certo :(

Comment: A codificação da tabela `produtos` também está em UTF8? Qual collate do UTF8 que está sendo usado?

Comment: Certificou que o navegador está renderizando a página como UTF8? Pode acontecer de enviar os headers em UTF8 e mesmo assim o navegador renderizar com outro charset.

Comment: O navegador está como UTF8. Na tabela produtos o collate é utf8_general_ci.

Comment: Reli sua pergunta e pelo código parece que é problema com o JSON. O JSON codifica os caracteres UTF8 no formato \u0000, e você está tirando essa barra invertida através do `stripslashes`, fazendo que a codificação do UTF8 feita pelo JSON seja inválida. Tente remover a stripslashes, já que está fazendo um `mysql_real_escape_string` e deixe gravar com a barra pra ver o que acontece.

Comment: Cara, fiz isso antes de você me responder, mas você me explicou o por que que tirando o stripslashes deu certo. lá no developer tools do google chrome, na parte de network, os dados ainda estão sendo enviados do jeito que mostrou acima (\u0000). É normal?

Comment: Sim, é normal. É uma sintaxe alternativa do Unicode para codificar caracteres. Deixe gravar dessa forma, não é errado.

Comment: Aaah entendi. Valeu por me ajudar, cara!